# Horizontally expand multiple UITextFields on rotation (via autolayout)

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitextfield, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I currently have three `UITextField`s in a `UITableViewCell`:

[image]

(ignore the orange background, that's just so that I can see the bounds of each `UITextField`).

There's a 1px `UIView` between each text field, to provide a visual divider.

Using autolayout, I would like to setup constraints so that all three text fields horizontally expand/grow in response to the device rotating to landscape. I have successfully setup constraints so that the text fields (and divider views) are positioned relative to each other:

[image]

However, this does not seem sufficient for autolayout to realise that it needs to resize all the text fields to compensate for the increased horizontal space when the device is rotated to landscape. Here are the conflicts that appear:

[image]

Setting the horizontal hugging priorities doesn't fix the problem, as each field needs a unique priority resulting in only the field with the lowest expanding, rather than all the fields.

Likewise, if I pin the width of two of the text fields then it works fine, but only one of the fields (i.e. the field with the unpinned width) will expand.

So it seems that the other constraints which I have added are fine, but I just don't know how to instruct autolayout to expand all three text fields the same. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I would suggest to get the text fields to expand equally in the horizontal direction:

Connect all three text fields as having "Equal Widths" in Interface Builder. Then, pin the horizontal spacing between the sides of the cell, the text field borders, and the separators to be a constant. Finally, you may need to set the middle text field to be centered horizontally.

Here is a test example:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much - I totally missed the Widths Equally constraint :)